# Is there a magic char, like &, that will match on an address regexp in sed?

Tags: unix, sed

I would like to write a bash script that returns the path of a mount point for a network mount on a Mac. What I've come up with so far is the following:

```
mount | sed -n -e "/^\/\/mynetaddr/s/\/\/mynetaddr on \([^ ]*\).*$/\1/p"
```

What this does is look for a network resource `//mynetaddr` and grab the mount point path from the mount command.

Is there a magic char, like &, that will match on an address regexp in sed? Alternatively, how do I rewrite the above so that I do not have to repeat the network address?

Comment: Can you give example on output from `mount` and what you like to get out from your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the address regex entirely:

```
mount | sed -n -e "s/\/\/mynetaddr on \([^ ]*\).*$/\1/p"
```

The `s///` command will then be matched against every line of the input, and only those in which a replacement occurs will be printed out (because that's how the `p` flag works).